# Getting Wordpress to show message when no posts exist in category

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get my blog to show a message to visitors when they visit the category main page *(ex: www.website.com/category-slug-here/)*, but can't seem to figure out the Wordpress Loop quite right. Here is what I started with in my theme's **index.php** file:

```
get_header(); ?>

<div id="page-wrap" class="blog-page blog-fullwidth container">

    <div id="content" class="blog-wrap <?php echo esc_attr($sidebarlayout); ?> columns">

        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'framework/inc/post-format/entry', get_post_format() ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'framework/inc/nav' ); ?>

    </div>

    <?php if($sidebar != 'no-sidebar'){ ?>
    <div id="sidebar" class="<?php echo esc_attr($sidebarorientation); ?> alt">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And here is how I tried to alter it:

```
get_header(); ?>

<div id="page-wrap" class="blog-page blog-fullwidth container">

    <div id="content" class="blog-wrap <?php echo esc_attr($sidebarlayout); ?> columns">

        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'framework/inc/post-format/entry', get_post_format() ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p>Sorry, looks like this category is empty!</p>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'framework/inc/nav' ); ?>

    </div>

    <?php if($sidebar != 'no-sidebar'){ ?>
    <div id="sidebar" class="<?php echo esc_attr($sidebarorientation); ?> alt">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

However, making this change doesn't seem to yield any results. Am I missing something here? Seems like this should work (but I'm also not a total PHP guru, which is why I came here to consult with the masses).   ;)

Comment: looks ok have you got the right file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wordpress the posts in category are shown in `archive.php` page .

Try to write the else condition in archive page instead of `index.php` page

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, @PrakashRao, for this answer -- totally helped me out, and you were right, it was the archive.php page I needed to make the adjustment in, not the index.php page. Thank you for the help!   :D